# Read in gutenberg text from NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, corpus

I am using the following method but it always throws me invalid file error:

```
import nltk
```

then

```
file=open(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('austen-persuasion.txt'),"r").read().split().lower()
wordcount={}

for word in file:
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1
print ("The frequency of each word in the text file is as follows :")
for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print (k, v)
```

The error is as follows

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-de499228f7ab> in <module>()
  1 import nltk
----> 2 file=open(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('austen-persuasion.txt'),'r').read().split()
  3 #file = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('austen-persuasion.txt')
  4 wordcount={}
  5 

TypeError: invalid file: ['[', 'Persuasion', 'by', 'Jane', 'Austen', '1818', ...]
```

Comment: You don't need to split() the readed file, the ntkl functionality does that for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @patito mentioned in the comment, you don't need to use `read` and you also don't need to use `split`, as nltk is reading it in as a list of words. You can see that for yourself:

```
>>> file = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('austen-persuasion.txt')
>>> file[0:10]
[u'[', u'Persuasion', u'by', u'Jane', u'Austen', u'1818', u']', u'Chapter', u'1', u'Sir']
```

You will also need to fix the indentations in your word count, but otherwise it will work for you.

Comment: indentations are perfectly fine, but then I can't use the .lower() on file to covert all texts to lowercase.

Comment: Just use list comprehension: `file = [word.lower() for word in file]`. And the indentation as you've pasted it above won't work - you need to indent after `for word in file:`

Comment: Thank you,
It worked perfectly fine. Sorry I pasted the code with wrong indents here.